# Images uploaded with CKeditor disappear after cron run

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

When i upload images with CKeditor in a directory inline-images - they disappear after each cron run. Why is that happened? I had a look at db table `file_managed` it's status set to 0.

What it might be?

Comment: How do you upload/use those images exactly? What field (type)? Maybe not a content entity? If so, open a bug report. Ckeditor tracks usage in text field types, if it's stored differently, it likely doesn't work

Comment: I am uploading them via image button in CKeditor (i have activated inline-images in text formats)

Comment: Did you end up figuring out what was wrong? I'm having the same issue and I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: This is the maintainer for this functionality in Drupal 8. This is NOT the right place to report bugs. Can you please report this bug at https://www.drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/drupal?component=editor.module, and provide steps to reproduce? Thank you!

Comment: Looks like there's a couple of bug reports at https://www.drupal.org/node/2801777 and https://www.drupal.org/node/2821423 already

Answer (score 0):

Whatever text editor are you using either Basic HTML, Restricted HTML or Full HTML.

In setting if `Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML` is enabled under the `Enable filters` setting. Check under the `Filter setting` in the list of `Allowed html tags`, `<img>` tag has been enabled or not? If not listed in that list, the image will be strip off from the content as for that case it is restricted html element.

**Update-1**

> [image]

Comment: It's not even on.

Comment: If the filter in question would be activated, the image wouldn't even be saved, it would simply be stripped off. However, the problem described and the problem I am facing myself is this: the image is saved, you can see it for a couple of hours afterwards, but after you run the cron responsible for cleaning orphan images, the image is gone. Any ideas why this is going on?

Comment: @Bogdan, are you uploading image using the image icon in  Ckeditor or are you inserting using HTML code?

Comment: @Bogdan I did check everything in my trial D8, site, nothing is stripping off any image, not internal image or external image. Hence I am posing the `filter` configuration of `Full Text Format`.